# Flot "legendColorBox" I cannot figure how to edit the javascript to  "fill" the colors?

Tags: javascript, flot

I don't know a whole lot about javascript so I can't really figure this one out. I changed some of the variable for the "legendColorBox" in the .js file, but I can't seem to get the color to fill up the entire box...  Please help!

See the keys "Misery Index" and "Unemployment Rate" ... They are only about70% filled. Please help!

[link to chart](http://www.amandabrucedesign.com/stuff/the_misery_index/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The cause is there is a

```
'width: 18px'
```

style on the legend color boxes. Not certain the root of that style. It looks like you should be able to over-ride with something like:

```
td.legendColorBox div > div {
   width: auto;
}
```

I have not tested that selector, but I think it is correct. The *best* solution is to find the root cause, but if not give the override a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing it to "auto" only makes the box much slender; I'm not sure what's going on here. Maybe I am not putting it into the JS correctly. But no matter the width size or auto, they keys are still not proportionate...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the width for the following:

```
.legendColorBox div div
{
    border-width: 8px !important;
}
```

(By default it is 5px).